# How to display previous 6 months data from current month in python

Tags: python

I have 3 months data like:

```
[
  {
    "Month": "Aug",
    "MonthNumber": "08",
    "NetAmount": 661.5
  },
  {
    "Month": "Oct",
    "MonthNumber": "10",
    "NetAmount": 245.1
  },
  {
    "Month": "Nov",
    "MonthNumber": "11",
    "NetAmount": 8877.4
  }
]
```

I want to display complete 6(current+previous) months data like:

```
[
  {
    "Month": "Jun",
    "MonthNumber": "06",
    "NetAmount": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Jul",
    "MonthNumber": "07",
    "NetAmount": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Aug",
    "MonthNumber": "08",
    "NetAmount": 661.5
  },
  {
    "Month": "Sep",
    "MonthNumber": "09",
    "NetAmount": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Oct",
    "MonthNumber": "10",
    "NetAmount": 245.1
  },
  {
    "Month": "Nov",
    "MonthNumber": "11",
    "NetAmount": 8877.4
  }
]
```

If data is not available of any month then display month with 0 value. Please guide.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code

Comment: Haven't tried anything.

Comment: Try to write the conditions for your cases. If there is an unexpected error or unexpected output, post your code for help. People won't do your homework here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried and get required results.

```
import time
result = []

months = {
    '1':'Jan',
    '2':'Feb',
    '3':'Mar',
    '4':'Apr',
    '5':'May',
    '6':'Jun',
    '7':'Jul',
    '8':'Aug',
    '9':'Sep',
    '10':'Oct',
    '11':'Nov',
    '12':'Dec',
}

if len(filter_result) > 0:
    x = 6
    now = time.localtime()
    monthData = [time.localtime(time.mktime((now.tm_year, now.tm_mon - n, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)))[:2] for n in range(x)]
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(monthData),0,-1):
        for data in filter_result:
            if monthData[i-1][1] == int(data.MonthNumber):
                data['NetAmount'] = formatDecimal(data['NetAmount'] / 1000)
                result.append(data)
                break
        if len(result) == count+1:
            count += 1
            continue
        else:
            salesData = {
                "Month" : months[str(monthData[i-1][1])],
                "MonthNumber" : "%02d" % (monthData[i-1][1],),
                "NetAmount" : 0
            }
            result.append(salesData)
            count += 1

return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You should list all shortnames of months in variable:

```
months = "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
data = [
    {
        "Month": "Aug",
        "MonthNumber": "08",
        "NetAmount": 661.5
    },
    {
        "Month": "Oct",
        "MonthNumber": "10",
        "NetAmount": 245.1
    },
    {
        "Month": "Nov",
        "MonthNumber": "11",
        "NetAmount": 8877.4
    }
]
```

To add missed months you can use next code:

```
completed_data = []
for item in data:
    num = int(item["MonthNumber"])
    for i in range(len(completed_data), num - 1):
        completed_data.append({
            "Month": months[i],
            "MonthNumber": f"{i + 1:02}",
            "NetAmount": 0
        })
    completed_data.append(item)
for i in range(len(completed_data), 12):
    completed_data.append({
        "Month": months[i],
        "MonthNumber": f"{i + 1:02}",
        "NetAmount": 0
    })
```

To print result indented you can use `json`:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(completed_data, indent=4))
```